# JBDC runs on development system but does not on production

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, gradle, amazon-ec2

I've attempted deploying a Scala application using a JDBC connection onto a production machine on EC2 (Amazon Linux).

On the development system (Windows, IntelliJ Idea IDE, Java 1.8.0_74) I can run the application and connect to the database without problems.

On the deployment machine (EC2 Amazon Linux, Java 1.8.0_101-b13) using the binary files and libs generated by gradle through the application plugin (more specifically distZip), I am unable to get a connection to the PostgreSQL database when I attempt running the app.

I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at SlackBot$.delayedEndpoint$SlackBot$1(SlackBot.scala:22)
        at SlackBot$delayedInit$body.apply(SlackBot.scala:14)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at SlackBot$.main(SlackBot.scala:14)
        at SlackBot.main(SlackBot.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at integrations.OrdersIntegration$.<init>(OrdersIntegration.scala:33)
        at integrations.OrdersIntegration$.<clinit>(OrdersIntegration.scala)
```

I have installed both postgresql and posgresql-jdbc on the instance using yum as well as upgraded to the latest version of Java.

I have also attempted downloading the latest JDBC from PosgreSQL site and adding that to the classpath with no success.

I am not entirely sure what I am missing, as I am able to run this code without issues on my development environment.
There are no options set for the VM nor are there any program arguments required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "No suitable driver" could also mean you are using the wrong JDBC URL.

Comment: I'm loading the PostgreSQL URL through an environment variable on both dev and production; env variables on both machines are the same for the user that runs the application

Comment: How do you know you have the right driver in the class path of the production?

Comment: CLASSPATH includes $APP_HOME/lib/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar in my run script and then runs java -classpath "$CLASSPATH" MyAppClass

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you might be right, it seems for some reason my implementation is not loading/reading the environment variables into the application hence preventing the driver from being loaded for a non-existent URL. Thank you for the help.-- I have confirmed this to be the case and have managed running the application. I forgot to "export" my variables. Thanks a lot!